# is the any problem use fast_io(A) problem with PIC16F877?

Tags: c, embedded, pic, proteus

When i define my code and run in proteus simulation, the leds which are connected to portA of PIC16F877 is not working. When i close the code like that "//use fast_io(A)" but i still use tris commands of port A, my leds are working which is connected to portA. So i can not lit the leds which is connected to portA when i use "#use fast_io(A)" command.I dont know why such thing occurs. First the leds are connected to portA.[image]

```
#use fast_io(A)
#use fast_io(B)
#use fast_io(C)

set_tris_a(0b00010000);
output_a(0x00);

set_tris_b(0b10111111);
output_b(0x00);

set_tris_c(0b00010000);
output_c(0x00);
```

Comment: By default PORTA is analog. Switch it to digital with the  `ADCON1` register.

Comment: When i write those above the main:#byte ADCON1 =0x9F
#bit PCFG3 =ADCON1.3
#bit PCFG2 =ADCON1.2
#bit PCFG1 =ADCON1.1
#bit PCFG0 =ADCON1.0 and those inside the main:  PCFG3=0;
 PCFG2=1;
 PCFG1=1;
 PCFG0=0; i still can not the leds

Comment: Please show your code and post a minimal reproducible example

Comment: Your diagram does not indicate what GPIO the LEDs are connected to.  Please state.